# React Input tags element not able to remove

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have form where it has Tags Input, I am able successfully add the tags,

But when i remove the tags, the state is not updating.

Here is the [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-christian-94x32)

App.js

```
const selectedTags = (tags) => {
    setTags(tags);
};

<TagsInput selectedTags={selectedTags} tags={tags} />
```

TagsInput.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTags(props.tags);
}, [props.tags]);
```

Comment: You're duplicating your `tags` state in the parent and in the child. It's not a good idea, since it can lead to this exact kinda issue, where they can get desynced. Just manage all the tag state in the parent and pass it down to the children as a prop

Comment: how should i approach this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `removeTags` function inside of the `TagsInput` component does not call `props.selectedTags(updatedTags);` after modifying the tags. Therefore the parent doesn't know about the change and does not trigger a re-render of those tags in the lower section. The TagsInput itself DOES re-render because you made a state change internally.

I would caution against duplicating state like this as its unnecessary and can cause desync issues that are a pain to identify and debug. The only time I recommend it is when a transformation is necessary or process intensive. In this case, that's not happening, so you should choose to make TagsInput [controlled or uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), not both.

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Update your `useEffect` method as shown below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.selectedTags(tags); // This will update the state in parent component as per your parent method implementation
  }, [tags, props]);
```